# Render tag span in component p-autocomplete

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a problem to render a label containing a span tag.
I perform a search normally only when selected the item in the text box is with a span tag
How to solve?

wrong - 10227 - Car new

right - 10227 - Car new

```
this.list= this.mapList.map(r => {
          return new Object(
            `<span>${res.cod}</span> - ${res.name)}`, 
            res
          );
```

Object

```
export class ObjectList {
  constructor(
    public name: any,
    public code: any,
  ) { }
}

<p-autocomplete>
<ng-template let-index pTemplate="item">
      <span [innerHTML]="index.label">{{ index.label }}</span>
    </ng-template>
</p-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Right and wrong are similar. There is a bracket here "${res.name)}" which must be causing an issue. Please create Stackblitz to help solve problem.

Comment: wrong - <span>10227</span> - Car new

Comment: seems like selectedItem template only works when you are using multiselect option. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Selected template does not work for single item selection.
You can read more here.

I suggest you to keep data in object rather than creating HTML in property and use `[field]` input. e.g.

```
formatItem(event) {
    console.log(event); // your object
    return event.id + " - " + event.name;
}
```

and in template:-

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" [suggestions]="filteredCountries"
  [field]="formatItem" [minLength]="1">
</p-autoComplete>
```

Comment: Did not work. What I want to do and when selecting the element with the span, remove it. In other words, select model 1 and click to leave it selected. And when you do that it should not appear <span class = 'class1'> 1156 </span> - name